# How to change the background image of a parent activity depending on what fragments are currently being displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, fragment_one (fragmentOne.class) and fragment_two (fragmentTwo.class).  These fragments are being displayed inside ActivityMain.class.

When fragment_one is being displayed I want to set Image A as the background for ActivityMain.class.

When  fragment_two is being displayed I want to set Image B as the background for ActivityMain.class

I can swap and set the background of ActivityMain.class when I am not using fragments (i use buttons as a test)....But, when I modify this for fragments I cannot get it to work.

Listed here you will see my ActivityMain.class

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity {

//set variables for use of pageradapter and swipe screen
MyPageAdapter adapter;
ViewPager pager;
Context context = this;
LinearLayout swipeHomeScreen;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_activity_nav);

    //Implement the adapater for the swipe screen on launch page and circle indicator
    adapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    swipeHomeScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeHomeScreen);

}
```

}

Here I have listed the code of one of my fragments where I am trying to share/pass the set the background image of ActivityMain.class...

```
public class ActivityNavSwipeTwo extends Fragment {

ActivityMain main;

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    main = (ActivityMain) activity;
};

public static ActivityNavSwipeTwo newInstance() {
    ActivityNavSwipeTwo fragment = new ActivityNavSwipeTwo();
    return fragment;
}

public ActivityNavSwipeTwo() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, null);
    main.swipeHomeScreen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Image2);
    return root;
}
```

}

My activity inflates the fragments fine, but the background image does not change.

How could I implement this for target api 23??

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Implement viewpager.onpagechangedlistener in your activity. Then add `view.setonpageselecterlistener`(this) in oncreated method. You can control selected fragment in implemented on pageselected method

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you have any parent layout(Relative/Linear) for your activity. So you have to do following:

- Create id of parent layout if not created.
- access from fragment and change the background color of that parent layout.

  Write this in Fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

  `relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);`
  `relativeLayout.setBackground(background);`